Struggling to Implement Eye Gaze for HoloLens 2 in Holographic Remoting
I am currently working on a project for the Hololens 2 and wanted to incorporate Eye Gaze for Holographic Remoting. I feel like I'm so close to fixing it and I'm just missing one checkbox or something. In the past, I have successfully implemented Eye Gaze in projects using Holographic Remoting, so I don't know why it suddenly doesn't work. I have followed the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/eye-tracking/eye-tracking-basic-setup?view=mrtkunity-2022-05
I also went through blogs by Joost van Schaik and countless posts on forums, but nothing seems to be fixing my issue. In Unity, there is an Eye Gaze Cursor GameObject, however, it follows the position of my head, not my eyes, and it only renders at the start and hides as soon as hands are detected. CoreServices.InputSystem?.EyeGazeProvider?.IsEyeCalibrationValid is returning true, so it isn't an issue with eye calibration. I just don't understand why this seemingly simple implementation has taken me all day. If anyone has any tips, they would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
To give some more context, the Eye Gaze cursor GameObject does appear when the scene first loads, however disappears when the hands are first detected and will not reappear. It also only follows the head and not the Eye Gaze. This post linked below is along the same lines as what I'm experiencing (although it doesn't look like they want eye gaze in the first place) but is above my level of understanding:
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/6320

Hi, so just to make sure, you are using MRTK2 or MRTK3

Hey! I am in MRTK version 2.8.3. I found out that CoreServices.InputSystem?.EyeGazeProvider?.IsEyeTrackingDataValid is false, but EyeTracking is enabled. Do you have any theories as to why that is? Thanks for the help!

One thing I should add is this may be a permissions thing. This HoloLens device is part of an organization and I don't see the "Apps" section in Privacy > Apps so I cannot grant Eye Tracking permissions. I am using Holographic Remoting and I can't find anything that says I have to do that for a remoting app, but I was wondering if you knew of any permission requirements for Holographic Remoting. Thanks!

Hi, can I know what eye gaze data providers you added in your MRTK profile? Moreover, did you try MRTK eye tacking examples?
